# Python Sockets: Client and Server both sending and receiving data from each other?

Tags: python, sockets, pickle

How can I get a socket to send data and then receive data? I followed some tutorials online and can get a server to send data to a client. My goal is to send a pickled image from the client to the server and then have the server respond with a text. Could someone provide a quick example of this bi-directional communication?

Comment: if you have problem with code then show it and full error message. If we show you some example then you may have again problem like with code from tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly by bi-directional communication or pickled image, but I can provide you with a sample tcp socket code to send an image. Skip to the full code section for the code you seek, which is at the bottom.
Here is a server example:

```
import socket                
  
# next create a socket object 
s = socket.socket()    
print("Initialized socket")      

port = 8986                
print("Port set to:" + str(port))

s.bind(('', port))         
  
s.listen(5)      
print("socket is waiting for client")         

while True: 
   c, addr = s.accept()      
   print('Client', addr )
  
   # send a thank you message to the client.  
   c.send('Demo'.encode()) 
  
   c.close()
```

and then a client sample will be like:

```
import socket                

s = socket.socket()    
print("Initialized socket")      

port = 8986            
print("Port set to:" + str(port))      

s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port)) 

print(s.recv(1024).decode() )
s.close()
```

Now to send to send an image you'll need read the image with pythons functions as a byte array and send it.

```
#On server-side
def read(self, filename):
    toRead = open(filename, "rb")

    out = toRead.read()
    toRead.close()
    
    return out
imgData = read("demo.jpg")
c.send(imgData)
```

On client-side:

```
imgData = s.recv(1024)

def write(self, filename, data):
    toWrite = open(filename, "wb")

    out = toWrite.write(data)
    toWrite.close()

write("Demo.jpg", imgData)
```

Full Code Server socket:

```
import socket    
        
def read(filename):
    toRead = open(filename, "rb")

    out = toRead.read()
    toRead.close()
    
    return out
imgData = read("demo.jpg")

# next create a socket object 
s = socket.socket()    
print("Initialized socket")      

port = 8986                
print("Port set to:" + str(port))

s.bind(('', port))         
  
s.listen(5)      
print("socket is waiting for client")         

while True: 
   c, addr = s.accept()      
   print('Client', addr )
  
   print("Sending image")  
   c.send(imgData) 
  
   print(c.recv(1024).decode())
   #c.close()
```

Full client-code:

```
import socket 

def write(filename, data):
    toWrite = open(filename, "wb")

    out = toWrite.write(data)
    toWrite.close()             

s = socket.socket()    
print("Initialized socket")      

port = 8986            
print("Port set to:" + str(port))      

s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port)) 

#The buffer size is important to set correctly.
#Below buffersize is 1024*8 which is about 8kB.
#Images more than 8kB will appear to be cut from the top.
#To prevent this you have to set a higher buffersize.
#Or you can have the server socket send the image length before
#sending the image byte-array.

imgData = s.recv(1024*8)
write("Demo.jpg", imgData)  

s.send("Received image".encode())
s.close()
```